# repeatIn(list, varname[, tagname]) -> NameError: name 'o' is not defined in openerp

Tags: openerp-7, rml

I have got this information from the official link of odoo documentation below:

repeatIn(list, varname[, tagname]) : repeat the current part of the template (whole document, current section, current row in the table) for each object in the list. Use varname in the template's tags. Since versions 4.1.X, you can use an optional third argument that is the name of the .RML tag you want to loop on.

***https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_1_openoffice_report.html***

I want to know how to use this repeatin because i have tried it like this:

```
  <para style="P7">[[   repeatIn(get_employee_lines((example.company_id,example.date_start,example.      date_end), o[,td]) ]]</para>

  <para style="P7">[[ o['name'] ]]</para>
```

And i have got this error:

```
   2015-09-02 11:37:00,027 8110 ERROR openerp openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval      
  'repeatIn(get_employee_lines((example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), o[,td])'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 288, in safe_eval
  return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 162, in test_expr
  code_obj = compile(expr, "", mode)
  File "<string>", line 1
  repeatIn(get_employee_lines((example.company_id,example.date_start,example.date_end), o[,td])
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  2015-09-02 11:37:00,027 8110 ERROR openerp openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval "o['name']"
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 288, in safe_eval
  return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  NameError: name 'o' is not defined
```

Please, who can resolve this problem.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

first, the syntax is wrong, opened three paranthesis and closed only two.

```
  <para style="P7"> [[ repeatIn(get_employee_lines(example.company_id,example.date_start,example.      date_end), 'o') ]]   </para>
```

if o is an object then user dot notation to access the values. If its a dictionary then use o['key']
here, dont know what get_employee_lines function returns, but it must return a list of [objects, or dictionaries etc] 
you can compare repeatIn to for loop in python

Comment: thanks for the answr friend:) but i want to try repeatIn(get_employee_lines((example.company_id,example.date_start,example. date_end), o[,td]) ]] which means Loop on every line and make a new table cell for each line